# Any experience using an RPi adressing several HDC1008?

Tags: pcb, sensor, raspberry-pi, i2c

The TI [HDC1008](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/hdc1008) humidity sensor allows having four sensors on one I2C bus. If I'm placing them 10 cm apart on the PCB, and connecting one end to a Raspberry Pi, would that work bus-wise? The address pins would be routed to GND or floating to have four addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed how the I2C bus is intended to be used.

Be carefull with the address pins (ADR0 and ADR1). They should be hardwired to VDD or GND (see the data sheet page 3), there is no mention of floating.

For the addresses available, see the data sheet page 10.

Comment: Also mind the pullups. rPi's internal pullups are weak (~50k). High speed and/or capacitance may require you to install your own stronger (lower value) pullup resistors on SCL and SDA. There are calculators online that will give you an allowable pullup value range for a given clock speed and total capacitance.

Comment: Thanks, should In connect all DataRdy ports of all Sensors to one line can I leave them floating?

Comment: The DS specifically says: "Data ready, active low, open-drain, requires a pull-up resistor to VDD. If not used tie to GND" on page 3.